# Why is importing `rq` much slower than importing `celery`?

Tags: python, celery, python-rq

I am unsure if I should use "celery" or "rq".

I am looking for a light-weight solution and my gut feeling told me that importing celery will be much slower than importing rq.

But the opposite is true. At least on my device:

```
> time python -c 'import rq'

real 0m0,115s
user 0m0,101s
sys  0m0,014s
```

```
> time python -c 'import celery'

real 0m0,035s
user 0m0,034s
sys  0m0,001s
```

I measured this several times - same result.

My prejudice was wrong. Why is importing rq three times slower?

Since somebody asked for it in a comment:

```
time python -c 'import huey'

real    0m0,096s
user    0m0,083s
sys     0m0,014s
```

Comment: It depends on what the module does when you import it. But importing is only done once when you start your script. Does this minimal time difference during import really matter?

Comment: why answer now when you can wait for the bounty ;)

Comment: @Matthias during developing I start python (or to precise pytest) over and over again (unfortunately (AFAIK) it is not possible to just reload the code in a long running interpreter). This means the interpreter starts again and again. I want this to be fast.

Comment: Why does the import speed matter to you? It is done once when the process starts anyway...

Comment: @DejanLekic see my above comment.

Comment: Since you are comparing Celery and rq, I suggest you try [Huey 2](https://huey.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as well.

Comment: @DejanLekic I added it.

Answer (score 3):

Roughly speaking, it has to do with the "for free" instantiation of a `LocalStack` in `rq.local`.  There isn't a similar complex thread-safe object that is created when importing celery.  That said you may see different times when you actually construct the application objects for each framework.